# How to display a ipython iframe in spyder python?

Tags: spyder

I have some code to generate anIpython Iframe , it works in Jupyter, but not in Spyder.  How to show the IFrame in Spyder or pop up html ?

In Spyder python, I wrote in the IPython interpreter :

```
from pivottablejs import pivot_ui
pivot_ui(df)
<IPython.lib.display.IFrame at 0x12a9b8d0>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To active pop in Spyder, we need to go to Preference / Graphics and enable Qt.
So all Ipython interactive will be into pop up QT.

Comment: I doubt this works in Spyder because `pivottablejs` requires the Jupyter notebook, as can be seen here: http://nicolas.kruchten.com/content/2015/09/jupyter_pivottablejs/

Comment: This does not work